# Getting ABI from contract source file offline

Tags: solidity, abi

Is there any way other than online solidity browser to get the ABI and bytecode of a contract?

Comment: You can get bytecode and ABI from solidity compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
> var greeterSource = 'contract mortal { address owner; function mortal() { owner = msg.sender; } function kill() { if (msg.sender == owner) suicide(owner); } } contract greeter is mortal { string greeting; function greeter(string _greeting) public { greeting = _greeting; } function greet() constant returns (string) { return greeting; } }'
undefined
> var greeterCompiled = web3.eth.compile.solidity(greeterSource)
undefined
> greeterCompiled
{
  greeter: {
    code: "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",
    info: {
      abiDefinition: [{...}, {...}, {...}],
```